# MS Access SELECT to UPDATE

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have looked through the site but I can't find what I am looking for.

I have a select query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT [StoreName] FROM [tbl_SB_Daily_Totals]
UNION ALL    
SELECT DISTINCT [StoreName] FROM [tbl_SBG_Daily_In\OutStats];
```

Which gives me exactly what I want BUT I need this to update into a table.

Ultimately what I need is a table that has one column which will have a unique list of stores from the two different tables above.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to do this.

```
INSERT INTO  NewTable (StoreName) SELECT StoreName FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT StoreName FROM [tbl_SB_Daily_Totals]
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT StoreName FROM [tbl_SBG_Daily_In\OutStats]) as x
```

Or

```
SELECT x.* INTO [NewTable] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [StoreName] FROM [tbl_SB_Daily_Totals]
UNION  SELECT DISTINCT [StoreName] FROM [tbl_SBG_Daily_In\OutStats]) x
```

Second option will create the table for you if not already exists,
but keep in mind that it will delete `NewTable` if already exist and create fresh every time you run this query.

Also use `Union` and not `Union All` if you want to remove duplicates from your combined result set.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem i have now is that if i run the query it appends data to the table. So my 55 unique records doubles each time i run the query. 

So i need the query to only update the table if a new unique value is found in the other two tables

Comment: either you can use Second option or you can have `NOT IN` appended to first query like this.    
`INSERT INTO  NewTable (StoreName) SELECT StoreName FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT StoreName FROM [tbl_SB_Daily_Totals]
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT StoreName FROM [tbl_SBG_Daily_In\OutStats]) as x  WHERE StoreName NOT IN (SELECT storename FROM NewTable )`

hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just use this query as a result set. something like:

```
insert into tbl_newTable (store_name)
select * from (
SELECT DISTINCT [StoreName] FROM [tbl_SB_Daily_Totals]
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT [StoreName] FROM [tbl_SBG_Daily_In\OutStats]) as tb1;
```